# .NET Memory Leak

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, memory, memory-leaks

After running our stress testing on our ASP.NET application access to internal web services, our mid-tier server (where we host ASMX .NET 3.5 web services) showed close to 1GB of memory consumption.

Upon the review of memory dump from mid-tier server, I have found over 1000 objects of Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer referenced by Web Services runtime itself.

Is this anything related to how our custom objects are getting serialized/deserialized in the web services layer? Could anyone shed more light on this?

When I did !gcroot on some of these 1000 objects, I got the following trace:
(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeFileWatcher)->
1c4bb450(System.Threading.Thread)->
18236aa0(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context)->
18236914(System.AppDomain)->
10409dc4(System.ResolveEventHandler)->
10409494(System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager)->
10409f30(System.Web.Compilation.MemoryBuildResultCache)->
103d115c(System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple)->
103d1174(System.Object[])->
103d2034(System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle)->
103d2080(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
1c24b97c(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
1c24b934(System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry)->
18363994(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType)->
183639c4(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
1c24aa5c(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
1c24a458(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMethod)->
1c248ae4(Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer26)

(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeFileWatcher)->
1c5ac4b0(System.Threading.Thread)->
1c52b5f0(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context)->
1c52b464(System.AppDomain)->
18823880(System.ResolveEventHandler)->
18822f50(System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager)->
188239e0(System.Web.Compilation.MemoryBuildResultCache)->
144631fc(System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple)->
14463214(System.Object[])->
14465088(System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle)->
144650d4(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
1446510c(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
1c5a580c(System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry)->
109e6e34(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType)->
109e6e64(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
1c5a4fcc(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
1c5a4a54(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMethod)->
1c5a44f4(Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer28)

(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeFileWatcher)->
108b38f0(System.Threading.Thread)->
1c1155ec(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context)->
1c115460(System.AppDomain)->
1030d348(System.ResolveEventHandler)->
1030ca18(System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager)->
1030d4a0(System.Web.Compilation.MemoryBuildResultCache)->
102d7ae4(System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple)->
102d7afc(System.Object[])->
102d7b1c(System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle)->
102d7b68(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
102d7bac(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
181ee124(System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry)->
10350eac(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType)->
10350edc(System.Collections.Hashtable)->
181ed260(System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[])->
181ed148(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMethod)->
181eb708(Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer61)

Thanks
BK

Comment: i strongly recommend to move to WCF.

Comment: I would love to. This is existing code and we have recently updated to ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try instrumenting your code with [ANTS Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) from Red Gate.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend us of the simply named *.Net Memory Profiler* from http://memprofiler.com/download.aspx.

You can use the full version for 14 days for free.

I have found it useful for this type of problem solving.  It will show you the reference tree.  Making fixing these type of problems really easy.